# To check that under a constructed complete metric on $(0,1)$ the sequence $1/n$ is not cauchy

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I was asked to construct a a metric on $(0,1)$ that induces the usual topology on it and that turns it into a complete metric space. The obvious choice is to define the metric as follows:

We have the bijection, 
$$ f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}, \ x\mapsto\tan\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
And we now define the metric as 
$$ d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)| $$
which makes $((0,1),d)$ complete, because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete in its usual metric, and it induces the standard topology because $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Now I have to check that the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n = 1/n$ is not Cauchy in this metric. And I'm unable to do that. Can I get some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\tan\left(\pi\left(\frac1n-\frac12\right)\right)=-\infty$. In particular, the limit does not exist in $\mathbb R$. Therefore, your sequence does not converge. Since your space is complete, your sequence cannot be a Cauchy sequence.